# Oracle SQL - Computed column

Tags: sql, oracle, date, status

I need some help in creating computed column called "Health_Stat" based on project Status, due date, completion date and sysdate. Am using Oracle db.

```
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Project Status |    Due Date     | Health_Stat |                              Notes                              |
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Planning       | Before due date | Not Required  |                                                                 |
| Planning       | After due date  | Not Required  |                                                                 |
| Cancelled      | Before due date | Not Required  |                                                                 |
| Cancelled      | After due date  | Not Required  |                                                                 |
| In Process     | Before due date | On Track      | 2 Days before due date "Health_Stat" should change to "At Risk" |
| In Process     | After due date  | Overdue       |                                                                 |
| On Hold        | Before due date | On Track      | 2 Days before due date "Health_Stat" should change to "At Risk" |
| On Hold        | After due date  | Overdue       |                                                                 |
| Complete       | Before due date | On Track      |                                                                 |
| Complete       | After due date  | Overdue       |                                                                 |
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Below is the table with data:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+
| PROJECTID |   STATUS   |  DUE_DATE  | COMPLETED_DATE |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+
|     10135 | Complete   | 5/31/2016  | 5/31/2016      |
|     10138 | Complete   | 8/31/2016  |                |
|     10259 | Complete   | 4/30/2017  | 5/5/2017       |
|     10335 | Complete   | 7/31/2017  | 8/31/2017      |
|     10340 | On Hold    | 12/15/2017 | 11/30/2017     |
|     10356 | Complete   | 9/7/2017   | 9/7/2017       |
|     10404 | Cancelled  | 10/22/2017 | 11/6/2017      |
|     10433 | In Process | 11/8/2017  | 2/2/2018       |
|     10443 | Planning   | 11/22/2017 | 11/14/2017     |
|     10455 | Planning   | 12/15/2017 | 12/13/2017     |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

Here is the query I tried:

```
SELECT projectid, 
       status, 
       due_date, 
       Trunc(completed_date) AS completed_date, 
       CASE 
         WHEN status IN ( 'In Process', 'On Hold', 'Complete' ) 
              AND due_date <= Trunc(completed_date) THEN 'On Track' 
         WHEN status IN ( 'In Process', 'On Hold', 'Complete' ) 
              AND due_date > Trunc(completed_date) THEN 'Overdue' 
         WHEN ( status IN ( 'Planning', 'Cancelled' ) ) THEN '' 
       END                   AS Health_Stat 
FROM   project_tracker 
ORDER  BY projectid
```

Below is the result am getting:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+
| PROJECTID |   STATUS   |  DUE_DATE  | COMPLETED_DATE | HEALTH_CHECK |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+
|     10135 | Complete   | 5/31/2016  | 5/31/2016      | On Track     |
|     10138 | Complete   | 8/31/2016  | -              | -            |
|     10259 | Complete   | 4/30/2017  | 5/5/2017       | On Track     |
|     10335 | Complete   | 7/31/2017  | 8/31/2017      | On Track     |
|     10340 | On Hold    | 12/15/2017 | 11/30/2017     | Overdue      |
|     10356 | Complete   | 9/7/2017   | 9/7/2017       | On Track     |
|     10404 | Cancelled  | 10/22/2017 | 11/6/2017      | -            |
|     10433 | In Process | 11/8/2017  | 2/2/2018       | On Track     |
|     10443 | Planning   | 11/22/2017 | 11/14/2017     | -            |
|     10455 | Planning   | 12/15/2017 | 12/13/2017     | -            |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Am having trouble on how to include sysdate in case statement and how to change health_stat to "On Track" if 2 days before due date. Since I have to compare project duedate with that of completion date and also sysdate. That's where am having trouble. Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Richa

Updating correct code in bold letters **:
Thanks and credits to @MatBailie

```
SELECT projectid, 
       status, 
       due_date, 
       Trunc(completed_date) AS completed_date, 
       CASE 
         WHEN status IN ( 'In Process', 'On Hold', 'Complete' ) 
              AND due_date **>=** Trunc(completed_date) THEN 'On Track' 
         WHEN status IN ( 'In Process', 'On Hold', 'Complete' ) 
              AND due_date **<=** Trunc(completed_date) THEN 'Overdue' 
         WHEN ( status IN ( 'Planning', 'Cancelled' ) ) THEN '' 
         WHEN status IN ( 'In Process', 'On Hold' ) 
              AND due_date >= **SYSDATE** + 2 THEN 'On Track' 
         ELSE '?' 
       END                   AS Health_Stat 
FROM   project_tracker 
ORDER  BY projectid
```

Comment: A computed column is a term usually reserved for a column actually attached to a table.  Do you really just mean you need to calculate this in your standard SELECT statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT projectid, 
       status, 
       due_date, 
       Trunc(completed_date) AS completed_date, 
       CASE 
         WHEN status IN ( 'In Process', 'On Hold', 'Complete' ) 
              AND due_date <= Trunc(completed_date) THEN 'On Track' 
         WHEN status IN ( 'In Process', 'On Hold', 'Complete' ) 
              AND due_date > Trunc(completed_date) THEN 'Overdue' 
         WHEN ( status IN ( 'Planning', 'Cancelled' ) ) THEN '' 
         WHEN status IN ( 'In Process', 'On Hold' )
              AND due_date >= SYS_DATE + 2 THEN 'On Track'
                                           ELSE '?'
       END                   AS Health_Stat 
FROM   project_tracker 
ORDER  BY projectid
```

Comment: Hi MatBailie,
Thanks for the query. This is the query I was looking for and having trouble with. I tested the code but am getting majority of results as Overdue though completed date is less than due date.

Comment: @richa you have the less than and greater than signs back to front. I do too, I copied them from you ;)

Comment: you are awesome. I've been pulling my hair from past few hours trying to fix it myself. I did change datatype from date to timestamp and vice versa but later only to know that I messed up less than symbol with greater than. My bad.